# After running Software Updater in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS I get a "software package failed" message

Tags: updates, update-manager

Complete NOOB here. I have multiple computers of different makes and models, all mini computers Gigabyte, Intel Nuc, and Beelinks.

After running an update in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS I get a "software package failed" message. It appears to complete, but it says it failed.

[image: screen capture of fail]

If I run update again, I either get "computer is up to date" or an update "remove old" packages/software, which also will report a failure, but if I run it after that, it will then say up to date.

[image: software is up to date]

Is this common/expected? I did see a similar question for [18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075766/18-04-software-updater-returns-package-operation-failed), but they updated their bios, and that fixed it for them, I had no such luck.

**update in reference to @stumblebee.**

```
$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for eyeon:
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:4 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:6 https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal-devel InRelease
Fetched 114 kB in 1s (79.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/source/Sources' as repository 'https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)
```

**AND**

```
$ /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
Expanded Security Maintenance for Applications is not enabled.
0 updates can be applied immediately.
9 additional security updates can be applied with ESM Apps.
Learn more about enabling ESM Apps service at https://ubuntu.com/esm
```

Comment: What is the outputs of `sudo apt update` and `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable` Please [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1490494/edit) your question and include this information.

Comment: @stumblebee Just updated it. Thanks. Another question, this particular box that I am running this test on is an AMD processor with an AMD video card, and I see reference to an intel library, which in this instance is probably not needed, any command to remove that? On this machine if I try and install software from the Ubuntu Software manager, I get an error of **Error while installing package: installed intel-i915-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10**

Comment: One problem is right there in your output: `W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/source/Sources' as repository 'https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal InRelease' does not seem to provide it (sources.list entry misspelt?)` Not sure why you added that source, but check the instructions for a typo. Or maybe it's old -- trying that URL in a web browser returns a server error suggesting it's not an apt repository anymore.

Comment: @Jackjackson You should delete ``https://repositories.intel.com/graphics/ubuntu focal InRelease``from your "Software updater" as @user535733
pointed out - It is invalid. After you have done that, you still have to run `sudo apt update` to update the "Software updater". It is my humble opinion to never use "Software Updater". Instead use `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable`  `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to update your system.

Comment: @Jackjackson In response to your comment question - " Error while installing package", It would be better to [Post a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) instead